# changing the value given by date("U") without changing the server time

Tags: php

ive been using date("U") allover my script when suddenly i found that i need to add timezone option in the website , which means all date("U") should look like `date("U") + $someTime` , is there any way i could change the time that the option date("U") displays without the need to modify the date("U")'s in the script and without modifying the server time ?

something like setting the date read by the 'date' function + or - some hours ???

Answer (score 2):

date("U") gives you the seconds since the Unix Epoch which is in GMT. How is the timezone relevant here?

Comment: if i want to add 2 hours to the current time , it would be date("U")+(3600*2) ... well i want to add these 2 hours in the first php file , where date("U") automatically will add the 2 hours after that line ...